# how do you print a bag datatype?

Tags: java

```
Bag<String> wordFrequencies = getWordFrequencies(text);
```

how do i see what this wordfrequencies bag contains..
 i ve used
org.apache.commons.collections15.Bag
org.apache.commons.collections15.bag.HashBag packages

Comment: that is how do i see what the bag contains

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String bagToString(Bag<?> bag) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object o : bag.uniqueSet() {

        sb.append(o);
        sb.append(":");
        int nItems = bag.getCount(o);
        sb.append(nItems);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```